# What is the equivalent of "@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})" in scala?

Tags: spring-boot, scala

I am trying to exclude the login class for Scala. I tried...

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = new Array[Class[_]](classOf[SecurityAutoConfiguration]))
```

But I get...

> Array constants have to be specified using the `Array(...)` factory method

What am I missing how do I exclude the security class in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says:

```scala
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = Array(classOf[SecurityAutoConfiguration]))
```